# LibreOffice Delete Solid Line

Tags: libreoffice

In LibreOffice a solid line is created when you enter three dashes (---) and press enter. These lines may become stuck to parts of the page. How do I remove them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As clarified by [AckNak](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=10997#p51480) the horizontal line borders are attached to the element they are near. If it is a paragraph I found simply cutting the paragraph, pasting it in to Notepad, cutting it from Notepad and then pasting it back to LibreOffice removes all the formatting. Only partially cutting the paragraph will not work.

Answer (score 4):

Those lines are created automatically using paragraph styling.

**If you notice it immediately** and know that you don't want it, you can override the border conversion by simply pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to "undo" the automatic conversion to a paragraph border.

You can **remove them** after the fact by selecting the entire paragraph, right-clicking on the selection and picking *Clear Direct Formatting*. That resets the formatting on the selection to that defined by the styles used.

If you rely on direct formatting rather than styles, you can right-click on the paragraph, pick *Paragraph* from the menu (for paragraph formatting), and under "Borders" remove the border by clicking on the line once. Click OK and the line is removed **without affecting any other styling.** You can also achieve a similar result by using the style lists to reapply the paragraph style.

**If you don't ever want** LibreOffice to do this conversion, go into Tools -> AutoCorrect Options -> Options and uncheck "Apply border".